# I can't start the upgrade form 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, release-management, do-release-upgrade

I first ran `sudo apt-get update`, then tried the following commands and they all failed

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
sudo do-release-upgrade -p
```

Each of the previous commands printed the same message:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade`...nothing

I tried running the `update-manager` from the dash multiple times...nothing

This is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy restricted main #Added by software-properties
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates restricted multiverse main universe #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security restricted multiverse main universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ saucy partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ saucy partner
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
```

What could I be missing ?

Comment: It might - and likely will - take some time to distribute to all of the Ubuntu users around the world... Software updates and upgrades will often be distributed in "waves" ("x" users at a time), in order to minimize the possibility of an unknown bug affecting all users.

Furthermore, the "April 17th" release date may not actually be April 17th in all parts of the world - for example, we're sitting on April 18th here in Australia...

Try it again in 24 hours - this should be available to most (if not all!) users by then.

Comment: For those seeking an answer, I changed my mirror to the best mirror (based on speed, ubuntu helps detecting that, choose to change your mirror and you'll find a button to do so), then I ran `sudo update`, then ``sudo do-release-upgrade` worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried `sudo do-release-upgrade` last nigth, I was told `No new release found` too. And, I found the [iso image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso) file can not be downloaded yesterday, because, there was no such a file there that time.

But this morning, I found I can download the image iso file, so...

I upgrade to 14.04 successfully via `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Try again, and good luck.

Comment: Yeah, it's available now - it hit Australia early this afternoon... It takes a bit for the new versions to distribute to all of the various sources on the Interwebs. I would imagine that most attempts to download it  either by Terminal or UI - would be successful by now...

Comment: A faster method is to change the mirror. I did so and it worked. Thank you.